# Disable Firefox's "Open Executable File" warning

Tags: firefox, security-warning

After updating Firefox to ver. 67.0, 
[a dialog box with the headline "Open Executable File?"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwwKI.png) 
is coming up every time I open an executable.

How can I disable those warnings? ([Unchecking these on Firefox's settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smBSp.png) didn't help).

Comment: (1) What operating system? (2) What do you mean by “open an executable”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Web Start (JNLP), newer Java versions configure (on Windows and MAC) a custom protocol handler that seems to avoid this dialog.  Similar can be done on Linux but would require some manual configuration which is explained here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/setup.html

So instead of http://example.com/foo.jnlp do this:  jnlp://example.com/foo.jnlp

Comment: Although it seems that replacing http:// with jnlp:// really bypasses this message, the site I'm using uses probably JS to open these Java apps, instead of supplying a direct link to the JNLP...
For example - https://mathnet.technion.ac.il/M/mathnet?action=load&key=jnlpP&homework=8&item=5&mathnetsessionid=mnlxqmrqfsclhfej
(Replacing https:// here with jnlp only causes an application error in Java, saying it's "Unable to launch the application"

Answer (score 5):

Go to `about:config` and paste this key in the search field:

```
browser.download.skipConfirmLaunchExecutable
```

It could not exist, but you can create it from there as a bool. Set it to `true`.